# Calculate run or streak across years in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate winning streaks in a MySQL DB. I created the following table to store the win/loss data:

```
"year"  "team_id"   "week"  "result"
"2007"  "1"         "1"     "W"
"2007"  "1"         "2"     "L"
"2007"  "1"         "3"     "W"
"2007"  "1"         "4"     "W"
"2007"  "1"         "5"     "W"
"2007"  "1"         "6"     "W"
"2007"  "1"         "7"     "W"
"2007"  "1"         "8"     "W"
"2007"  "1"         "9"     "W"
"2007"  "1"         "10"    "L"
. . .
```

This data spans 4 years across 12 teams, for 13-16 weeks per year.

To calculate the winning streaks, I use the following query:

```
SELECT
    team_id,
    result,
    year,
    MIN(week) as StartDate, 
    MAX(week) as EndDate, 
    COUNT(*) as Games
FROM (
    SELECT
        year,
        week,
        team_id,
        result,
        (   SELECT
                COUNT(*) 
            FROM
                win_loss_temp wl2 
            WHERE
                wl1.team_id = wl2.team_id
                and wl2.result <> wl1.result
                and wl2.year <= wl1.year
                AND wl2.week <= wl1.week) as rungroup
    FROM
        win_loss_temp wl1) A
WHERE result = 'W'
GROUP BY year, team_id, result, rungroup
ORDER BY Games desc
LIMIT 15;
```

This gives the following result:

```
team_id    result    year    StartDate    EndDate    Games
----------------------------------------------------------
5          W         2007    1            12         12
1          W         2007    3            9          7
5          W         2008    2            7          6
. . .
```

This is correct/expected output...within a single given year.

My issue is spanning multiple years. Say a team finishes 2007 on a 3-game win streak, and then wins the first 4 games of 2008. That should be recorded as a 7-game win streak in total (7 wins without recording a loss). But so far I cannot figure out how to modify the above query to accommodate spanning years.

I even tried creating a new field in the table that was year concatenated with week (e.g. `2007.13` for Week 13 of 2007), but had no success using that field instead of year and week separately. Gave funky results.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisiting this to revise my previously incomplete (unbeknownst to me until now) answer. Thanks to [this external resource](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/detecting-runs-or-streaks-in-your-data), which addresses my question completely, I was able to tweak the query to fit my specific need perfectly.

First, I created a view `run_groups` defined as such:

```
select
    `GR`.`team_id` AS `team_id`,
    ((`GR`.`year` * 100) + `GR`.`week`) AS `GameDate`,
    `GR`.`result` AS `Result`, (
        select
            count(0)
        from
            `jaddl`.`game_results` `G`
        where
            ((`G`.`result` <> `GR`.`result`) and
            (`G`.`team_id` = `GR`.`team_id`) and
            (`G`.`playoffs` = `GR`.`playoffs`) and
            (((`G`.`year` * 100) + `G`.`week`) <= ((`GR`.`year` * 100) + `GR`.`week`)))) AS `RunGroup`
from
    `jaddl`.`game_results` `GR`
where
    (`GR`.`playoffs` = 0)
```

Then I can utilize that view to create another view, which gives me my final results which I can query against for data mining purposes...my end game.

```
select
    `run_groups`.`team_id` AS `team_id`,
    `run_groups`.`Result` AS `Result`,
    min(`run_groups`.`GameDate`) AS `StartDate`,
    max(`run_groups`.`GameDate`) AS `EndDate`,
    count(0) AS `Games`
from
    `jaddl`.`run_groups`
group by `run_groups`.`team_id`, `run_groups`.`Result`, `run_groups`.`RunGroup`
order by count(0) desc, `run_groups`.`Result` desc, min(`run_groups`.`GameDate`)
```

This outputs data like so:

```
team_id  Result  StartDate  EndDate  Games  
      1      -1     201507   201606     13  
      7      -1     201603   201702     13  
      5       1     200701   200712     12  
      1      -1     201202   201213     12  
      2       1     200908   201005     11  
     12       1     201209   201305     10  
      5       1     201401   201410     10  
      4      -1     200813   200908      9  
     11      -1     201112   201207      9
```

(A `result` of `1` is a win, `-1` is a loss.) And voila! The dataset I need to query for all streak-related statistics. Shoutout to @eggyal for his excellent suggestion of using `year*100+week` instead of concatenating years and weeks with leading zeros as a string.

Comment: Oh.  I commented before I saw you had posted this.  Yes, this is almost certainly your problem.  Better just to use an integer than fiddle around with strings and padding: `YEAR*100 + WEEK`.

Comment: @eggyal Great minds think alike. :) But see my latest edit in this answer...the issue isn't quite resolved.

Comment: yeah, change your subselect to also select the concat(year, week) and remove the year from your select and your group by.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    team_id,
    result,
    year,
    MIN(CONCAT(year,week)) as StartDate, 
    MAX(CONCAT(year,week)) as EndDate, 
    COUNT(*) as Games
```